# Prove that if $b \ge -1$ and $b \neq 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove that if $b \ge -1$ and $b \neq 0$

$$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4\lvert b \lvert} \ge \sqrt{b+1}$$

Not sure how to start with this one since $b$ can be negative too so I can't square both sides

Comment: That's irrelevant, $4b^2+b+1=(2b+1/4)^2+15/16$ isn't negative.

Comment: But, please, *DON"T* square both sides.  You *can* and you will get .... a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't square both sides.  You'll get a monster on the LHS that will not help you.

Note $|b| = \sqrt{b^2}$

So $|b|\sqrt{b +1} = \sqrt{b^2(b+1)}$

By AM-GM $\sqrt{b^2(b+1)} \le \frac {b^2 + b + 1}2$

which .... doesn't help us.

But $2|b| = \sqrt{4b^2}$ so......

$2|b|\sqrt{b+1} = \sqrt{4b^2(b+1)} \le \frac {4b^2 + b + 1}2$

which does.

=====

BTW:

Bear with me.

Let $f(b) = 4b^2 + b + 1$.  We know that is continuous.  If you graph it will be a continuous curve.

If $4b^2 + b + 1 = 0$ then $b = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 16}}{8}$.  These are not real so there are no real solutions.

So $4b^2 + b + 1$ never equals $0$.  For $b=0$ then $4b^2 +b + 1 = 1> 0$. If $f(b)$ is ever less than $0$ we must have a discontinuity where $f(b)$ "jumps" from positive to negative without passing through $0$ in between.

So $4b^2 + b + 1 > 0$.

So you *can* square both sides.  But you shouldn't.

... oh.... d'oh!...

By square completion:

$4b^2 + b + 1 = (2b)^2 + 2*(2b)*(\frac 14) + (\frac 14)^2 + \frac {15}{16} =$

$(2b + \frac 12)^2 + \frac {15}{16} > 0$.

Maybe that's an easier argument.

BUt... it's beside the point.

====

Alternative solution

$\frac {4b^2 + b + 1}{4|b|} \ge \sqrt{b+1} \iff$

$4b^2 + b + 1 \ge \sqrt{b+1}*4|b|\iff$

$4b^2 + b + 1 - 4|b|\sqrt{b+1} \ge 0$.

If I con show $4b^2 + b + 1 - 4|b|\sqrt{b+1} = M^2$ for some expression $M$ we will be done as $M^2 \ge 0$.

So If we let $\sqrt{b+1} = y$ we get $4b^2 + b + 1 - 4|b|\sqrt{b+1} =4b^2 + y^2 -4|b|y$ which... pretty much does it.

$4b^2 + y^2 -4|b|y= 4b^2 - 4|b|y + y^2 = (2|b| - y)^2$

Which if you turn in:

> $(2|b| - \sqrt{b+1})^2 \ge 0$
>
> $4b^2 - 4|b|\sqrt{b+1} + b+ 1 \ge 0$
>
> $4b^2 + b + 1 \ge 4|b|\sqrt{b+1}$
>
> $\frac {4b^2 + b+1}{4|b|} \ge \sqrt{b+1}$

would look really slick and make you appear brilliant, and effectively hide all the hair pulling and false leads and banging head against the wall that we all go through.

Comment: Do you have any general tips on spotting what to use when proving something?

Comment: Not really.  I've been seeing a lot of AM-GM questions lately. Also with squaring brings powers apart.  Seeing things already squared make me think it a matter of showing something is a square and thus greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to 
$$4b^2+b+1-4\lvert b\rvert\sqrt{b+1}\ge0\iff\bigl(2\lvert b\rvert- \sqrt{b+1}\bigr)^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: How did you simplify it to $\bigl(2\lvert b\rvert- \sqrt{b+1}\bigr)^2$?

Comment: Simply with $(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy$, taking into account that $\lvert b\rvert^2=b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $A $ and $B $ are $\ge 0$, then

$$\frac {A+B}{2}\ge \sqrt {A}\sqrt {B} $$
it is AM-GM.
It comes from the fact that

$$A+B-2\sqrt {AB}=(\sqrt {A}-\sqrt {B})^2\ge 0.$$

Take $$A=4b^2$$ and $B=... $.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b+1$ appear twice it is reasonable to write $a=b+1$, or even better $a=\sqrt{b+1}$. And since $|b|^2= b^2$ it is also nice to write $c=|b|$. So you have to prove: $${4c^2+a^2\over 4c}\geq a$$ and this is equivalent to $4c^2+a^2\geq 4ac$ and this is $(2c-a)^2\geq 0$.