# Prove $\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4\left|b\right|}\ge \sqrt{b+1}$, $b\ge -1,\:b\ne 0$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I've literally tried everything for this question. I think I'm supposed to use the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality (AGM) but I don't know how to apply AGM to this question so I tried algebraic manipulation and it feels like I'm getting nowhere.

$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4\left|b\right|}\ge \sqrt{b+1}$

$\frac{\left(4b^2+b+1\right)^2}{16b^2}\ge b+1$

$b^2+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{9}{16}+\frac{1}{8b}+\frac{1}{16b^2}\ge b+1$

$b^2-\frac{b}{2}-\frac{7}{16}+\frac{1}{8b}+\frac{1}{16b^2}\ge 0$

$\frac{16b^4+2b-7b^2-8b^3+1}{16b^2}\ge 0$

$16b^4+2b-7b^2-8b^3+1\ge 0$

I don't know where to go from here.

**I don't want a complete answer, just give me a hint, thanks.**

**EDIT: I think I figured it out**:

AGM = $\frac{x+y}{\:2}\ge \sqrt{xy}$
= $\frac{x+y}{\:2}\ge \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$

Let x = $4b^2$ and y = $b+1$

Then we have, by AGM:

$\frac{\left(4b^2\right)+\left(b+1\right)}{2}\ge \sqrt{4b^2}\sqrt{b+1}$

$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{2}\ge 2\left|b\right|\sqrt{b+1}$

$\frac{\frac{4b^2+b+1}{2}}{2\left|b\right|}\ge \sqrt{b+1}$

$\frac{4b^2+b+1}{4\left|b\right|}\ge \sqrt{b+1}$, as needed. QED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Remember that $x^2 =|x|^2$ and write LHS as $${4b^2\over 4|b|} +{b+1\over 4|b|}$$

Comment: The polynomial has no rational roots; how does that help factor it?

Comment: It seems that you answered an identical question before: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2423768/42969.

Comment: You are missing a point here. He wants only a hint not a solution. This question is not identical to the one you pointed. As mathematican you should now what does identical means. @MartinR

Comment: You question is pointless. It simply does not. @aschepler

Comment: I'm so lost, I don't think you can factor $16b^4+2b-7b^2-8b^3+1$ (or I don't know how to). And with the hint you gave me, I tried squaring both sides I get $b^2+\frac{b^2+2b+1}{16b^2}\ge b+1$ which seems to be a dead end...

Comment: My fault, rational root theorem is usless here.

Comment: I think I figured it out, can someone check my edit plz

Comment: It is correct. @Yaya123